# Зачем нужен gluegen и кроcсплатформеннен ли JOGL?

Tags: java, opengl

Читал что нужно сделать чтобы подключить JOGL к проекту. Возникли следующие вопросы:

1. Зачем нужен gluegen? Насколько я знаю, это что-то вроде транслятора с C/C++ (не помню) на Java. Но я же подключаю уже готовые Java-библиотеки, мне нужна трансляция с C/C++.
2. Кроссплатформенность JOGL. Когда я подключаю JOGL я подключаю библиотеки jogl-all-natives-PLATFORM-CPUARCH.jar и gluegen-rt-natives-PLATFORM-CPUARCH.jar. Но из их названия видно, что они работают под конкретной платформой. Так ли это? То есть я не могу запустить приложение под Windows, когда оно было собрано с linux-библиотеками, нужно для каждой платформы собирать проект отдельно? Нет ли какого-нибудь способа собирать проект с библиотеками которые будут работать везде (т.е. кроссплатформенными)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2) Не совсем, это просто набор JNI с++, для каждой платформы нужно качать свою библиотеку(под платформу) или таскать все вместе. Вы врятле найдете кросплатформеный вариант. для игр можно пробывать jMonkeyEngine, основан на собрате JOGL, LWJGL. Хотя возможно поменять.

1) https://jogamp.org/gluegen/www/ тут написано что он сам генерирует нужные JNI для конкретной платформы.

Comment: Вы случайно не перепутали пункты местами?

Comment: я изначально хотел ответить на 2-ой вопрос, но гугланул первый и нашел сылку для первого

Comment: и думаю автору нужно двигаться именно через gluegen

Comment: 2) что "Не совсем"? 1) Какие JNI он генерирует?

Comment: 1) для вызова OpenGl функций джаве нужно с/с++ методы, нет доступа к железу напрямую( у джавы), вот он генерирует методы учитывая конкретныю платформу. OpenGL предоставляет API, которые можно вызвать из с/с++, вот такая информация и генерируется

Comment: 2) Кросплатферменый, так как нужны JNI

Comment: И ещё: что значит "автору нужно двигаться именно через gluegen"?

Comment: он хотел двигатся в сторону кросплатформености, это значит либо таскать все библиотеки либо узнать больше про gluegen, так как он позиционирует себя как генератор таких зависимостей, конечно возмодны нюансы вот поэтому стоит и погуглить или задать более конкретный вопрос по данной тематике(на счет gluegen)